# Calculating the amount of seconds between 2 dates in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been looking around to learn how to calculate the time between 2 certain dates: the date right now, and the date we are calculating from.

I found this snippet and edited it abit to my needs:

```
function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
    var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate(), a.getHours(), a.getMinutes(), b.getSeconds());
    var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate(), b.getHours(), b.getMinutes(), b.getSeconds());

    return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / 1000);
}
```

It calculates the amount of seconds between 2 dates.

This method is getting called by this piece of code:

```
var j = new Date('July, 05, 2012');
var n = new Date();

setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = dateDiffInDays(j, n);
}, 1000)
```

What is that it is auto updating every second, wich i thought i did with the `setInterval` method. Why is'nt this working?

Also, whenever i re-run the code, it doesnt even update the number.

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qKUCe/)

Comment: 1 quick question. You are using `Date.UTC(a.getFullYear().......)` is there a reason you use this over `b.getTime() - a.getTime()`??

Comment: @WORMSS Yeah, because i want to calculate the years, months, days and minutes and seconds aswell.

Comment: You may wish to look more into your date code, as you have not taken stuff like timezones into account. Also, a.getTime() returns you the UTC time exactly like Date.UTC, but with only 1 call. (Also includes timezones calculated).

Comment: For a (almost complete) list of headaches of what you are trying to deal with, you may wish to watch this video (IN FULL).. **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY** .. It may not help you write the code you are after, but it may help you recognise problems when dealing with dates you had not considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the correct version:

```
var j = new Date('July, 05, 2012');
setInterval(function () {
    var n = new Date();
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = dateDiffInDays(j, n);
}, 1000);
```

`n` was never updated in your code.

`j` is left alone because its value is constant. But I moved `n` inside the periodical function so it gets a new value at each period.

---

Oh, and you made an error on this line:

```
var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate(), a.getHours(), a.getMinutes(), b.getSeconds());
```

That should be:

```
var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate(), a.getHours(), a.getMinutes(), a.getSeconds());
```

Comment: Ah okay, i see. But why arent the seconds increasing while i'm refreshing the page or re running the code snippet ? http://jsfiddle.net/qKUCe/1/

Answer (score 2):

Because n is not being recreated, so you are saying how many seconds from the date you specified, and the date that the `n` variable was created. Use:

```
setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = dateDiffInDays(j, new Date());
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

please check this out if you are looking for [**a working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qKUCe/2/).

I have updated the code a bit as I dint understand the need of re creating the date objects inside the function when you have them passed as function parameters.

```
setInterval(function () {
    var n = new Date();
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = dateDiffInDays(j, n);
}, 1000)

var j = new Date('July, 05, 2012');

// a and b are javascript Date objects then why are you re creating the date objects again?
function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
    var _MS_PER_DAY = 1000;
    return Math.floor((b.getTime() - a.getTime()) / _MS_PER_DAY);
}
```